# Ubuntu hangs on boot when NFS-mounting entries in /etc/fstab, but they mount cleanly otherwise

Tags: nfs, ubuntu-9.10

I'm managing several Ubuntu 9.10 servers that NFS mount several folders (including /home). I'd like these folders to be mounted at boot time. I would like to have several entries in my /etc/fstab to accomplish this, e.g.

```
192.168.1.100:/home           /home           nfs     rw 0 0
192.168.1.100:/usr/ansys_inc  /ansys_inc      nfs     ro 0 0
```

Unfortunately, with this configuration, the servers usually (although not always) hang during the bootup sequence when trying to do the NFS mount.

if I comment out these fstab entries, reboot the machine, uncomment them and mount them manually using the shell, the folders mount cleanly.

I'm not sure how to go about debugging this problem. It seems like it has something to do with the boot sequence, that some relevant process hasn't been started by the time the OS tries to mount the folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `_netdev` option for that filesystem in `/etc/fstab`.

> ```
>   _netdev  
>
>           The filesystem resides on a device that requires network  access
>           (used  to  prevent  the  system  from  attempting to mount these
>           filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).
> ```

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue, on CentOS 5.3, i did

1) enable;

```
spanning-tree portfast default
```

on the switch (cisco)

2) changed the nfs mount in fstab to

```
server:/dir   /dir   nfs   _netdev,rw,bg,hard,intr   0  0
```

and now it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that networking starts **before** NFS. 
I've seen this happen a bunch of times on Debian boxes.

Comment: How would one go about doing that?

Comment: @adam-l-taylor please check the first answer to this question. That is the correct way of fixing the mount issue. But as far as the procedure of changing boot order, it is different for Systemd and SysV or rc.d systems, so one would need to know what kind of system you are running to give you a correct answer.